# Is there an English equal for hindi saying "Bandar ke Haath me ustra" or "Razor in hands of a monkey"

Tags: phrases, expressions, idioms, proverbs

Is there a English equal for hindi saying

> Bandar ke Haath me ustra

which literally means "Razor in Monkey's hand"  as if Never give a risky job to a people who is like a monkey. If he has a razor he will not only either get himself killed but also kill other.

Example: A important client is coming to meet the CEO of a large corporation. The manager is told by the CEO to arrange a presentation to secure this big account with the client. The manager selects a newbie or an old fool or an empty-suit (either of whom are not fit for the job). So hearing this two experienced efficient employees discuss the matter.

One says to the other: Manager has given Razor (ustra) in hands (haat) of a monkey (Bandar) as in "Bandar ke haat mein ustra" or "Razor in hands of a monkey"

Comment: The word **E**nglish is spelled with a capital letter. EDIT Grammatically, it should read: "Is there **an** English equivalent...." Personally, I'd get rid of the actual Hindi phrase in the title, not in the question body, but it's your question!

Comment: @Mari-Lou A  Purpose for keeping the hindi version is that people like me or any local member usually get lured to respond or at least glimpse through the responses when the actual hindi or any other local indian known language sayings are put in the title as we are familiar with it rather than the translation which may not attract or make sense to many of us (if in the case the OP has made roundabout translation).

Comment: Your interest in the post is welcome. You may not have known, though, that the comment thread is reserved for *helping to improve the question*: friendly clarifying questions, suggestions for improving the question, relevant but transient information, and explanations of your actions. Please avoid
answering questions in comments.
A welcoming place for discussion of posts (or anything else) is our [English Language & Usage Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95).

Answer (score 2):

It sounds most like the idiom "**to run with scissors**". It generally means to willfully act in a reckless or foolish manner.  It can be used in your example:

> One says to the other: Manager is sure **running with scissors** by giving the
>   presentation to *that guy*. Didn't anyone tell him he shouldn't **run with scissors**?

https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/scissor

Answer (score 1):

Actually an idiom with an opposite meaning, but should be good to go in the *negative sense*: ***in safe hands*** (also *in good hands* or *in a safe pair of hands*).

> The manager has ***not*** put the responsibility **in safe hands**.

TFD(idioms):

> **[in safe/good ˈhands](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+safe+hands)**
>
> being taken care of by a responsible person or organization, and
>   unlikely to be harmed or damaged
>
> When the child is with my mother, I know she’s in good hands.
>
> Farlex Partner Idioms Dictionary © Farlex 2017